# Intuitive explanation for p ∨ q → r ≡ ( p → r) ∧ (q → r)

Tags: discrete-mathematics, logic

Although, it is possible to prove the above equivalence using truth tables, I don't know how to prove it without using truth tables.Can someone explain it in plain english?

Comment: You can draw set diagrams and convince yourself.

Comment: @Shailesh I don't know how.

Comment: Don't you have a typo in the statement?

Comment: @TedShifrin where?

Comment: Shouldn't both be $\vee$ or both be $\wedge$?

Comment: @TedShifrin  No , the statement is correct.

Comment: Yes, you're right, of course. Apologies.

Comment: The right hand side is "P is a road that leads to R, and Q is a road that leads to R"; the left hand side is "You can get to R by either of the roads P and Q"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is sometimes referred to as Inference by Cases.

It's easy if you bear in mind that $\mathcal{S} \Rightarrow \mathcal{T}$ is equivalent to $(\lnot \mathcal{S}) \lor \mathcal{T}$ where $\mathcal{S}$ and $\mathcal{T}$ are any wffs.

\begin{align}
[(P \lor Q) \Rightarrow R] &\Leftrightarrow [\lnot(P \lor Q) \lor R] \\
&\Leftrightarrow [(\lnot P \land \lnot Q) \lor R] \quad \text{DeMorgan's} \\
&\Leftrightarrow [(\lnot P \lor R) \land (\lnot Q \lor R)] \\
&\Leftrightarrow [(P \Rightarrow R) \land (Q \Rightarrow R)].
\end{align}

Answer (score 3):

This is a neat little identity. I would put it like this: there's a red button that sets off the bomb. If either Angie or Bill pushes it, then the bomb will go off.

$$(\text{Angie pushes the button}) \vee (\text{Bill pushes the button}) \implies (\text{explosion})$$

But we also know that, independently, if Angie pushes the button then the bomb will go off **and** if Bill pushes the button, the bomb will go off.

$$
((\text{Angie pushes the button}) \implies (\text{explosion}))
\wedge
((\text{Bill pushes the button} \implies (\text{explosion}))$$

Comment: Quite an explosive proof

Comment: This falls in the trap I'm complaining about. Why is the *and* needed? The logic is muddled here by the English words.

Comment: @TedShifrin: I'm not sure I understand your objection, though I'd like to. For me, the *and* is needed to represent the conjunction.

Comment: @TedShifrin All of the relevant words (and, or, if/then) have been replaced by the logical symbols. I don't understand how the logic is muddled by the English.

Comment: Sure. But, following your words, surely if either one pushes the button, the bomb explodes. Your words do not sufficiently explain the conjunction of *the implications*!

Comment: @TedShifrin How so? I think the conjunction of the implications is explained perfectly well.

Comment: @TedShifrin: Ah, I understand your objection better. The sentence that was intended to explain this was the second one -- "if Angie pushes the button then the bomb will go off, and if Bill pushes the button, then the bomb will go off." Would you write it differently?

Comment: But this line of explanation leads me to think either one suffices, not that both are needed.

Comment: @TedShifrin If s/he only wrote "If Bill pushes the button then the bomb went off," then it wouldn't be equivalent, because this means that if Angie pushed it maybe it wouldn't go off. So one doesn't suffice; you need both.

Comment: So what? Only one of them needs to set it off. This is subtle, and I fell in the trap originally.

Comment: @TedShifrin With $\land$ in the second sentence, it says that only one of them _needs_ to set it off. With $\lor$ in the second sentence, it says that at least one of them _can_ set it off. (And please write `@columbus8myhw` in comments addressed to me; I don't get notified otherwise.)

Comment: @TedShifrin Disregard my last (deleted) comment if you saw it. It was wrong, and I understand your objection a lot better now.

Comment: @columbus8myhw: I believe there is something to understand, but I still don't get it. Can you help?

Comment: Take the last English sentence in the post, and replace **and** with **or**. "If Angie pushes the button then the bomb will go off **or** if Bill pushes the button, the bomb will go off." Now, it's not equivalent to the first sentence, but it's not immediately clear that it's inequivalent; the logic gets muddled in the English.

Comment: @columbus8myhw: Okay, I see that and see how it could be unclear.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps it's best to think about the only way an implication can fail: The hypothesis must be true and the conclusion false. So the left statement fails if and only if $P\vee Q$ is true and $R$ is false, i.e., if at least one of $P$ and $Q$ is true and $R$ is false. The right statement fails if and only if (at least) *one* of $P\implies R$ and $Q\implies R$ is false, so either $P$ or $Q$ must both be true and $R$ must be false.

Answer (score 1):

It helps to think of examples. Let $p$ be "Alfred wants to play basketball," $q$ be "Bertrand wants to play basketball," and $r$ be "We will play basketball."

The first statement reads "If either Alfred or Bertrand want to play basketball, we will play basketball." The second statement reads "If Alfred wants to play basketball we will play basketball; if Bertrand wants to play basketball we will play basketball." Do you see why these are the same?

This isn't a formal proof, but you asked for an intuitive explanation.

Comment: If we had a key, we could open the door, and if we knew the password, we could open the door. If we had either a key or a password, we could open the door.